# Translate this sentence. Rewrite it in your own words. Why does Conroy reference all of these works of literature in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, american-english, literature, quotations

**I have read like a man on fire my whole life because the genius of English teachers touched me with the dazzling beauty of language.**-Pat Conroy
This is from "A Letter to the Editor of the Charleston Gazette," and I accept all help including but not limited to constructive criticism, and homework help. I just don't know what Conroy means by this sentence and the literature that he has "Easter egged" in his quote has completely eluded me. I'm sorry.

Comment: Are you asking us to do your homework?

Comment: Are there in fact aspects of the sentence that you do not understand? What do you think it means? Also, we can hardly comment on why Conroy mentions works of literature in a part of the paragraph that you have not quoted nor linked to.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Where does he reference works of literature?

Comment: @Lambie It looks to me as if the OP has only quoted part of the paragraph, and references are in parts not quoted..

Comment: @DavidSiegel Then, my question is relevant.

Comment: @Lambie I agree. Giving the exact source of the quote would also be helpful.

Comment: Several online sources cite this quote to * A Lowcountry Heart: Reflections on a Writing Life* by Conroy. Others to "A Letter to the Editor of the Charleston Gazette,"  from *Beach Music*.  https://barnabaspiper.com/2015/05/fresh-friday-quote-pat-conroy.html gives what seems to be the whole paragraph, which refers to *Don Quixote*, *Anna Karenina*, *Lonesome Dove*, *Beloved*, *Ulysses*, *the Arabian Nights*, and *A Prayer for Owen Meany*. Quite a list, and merely examples.

Comment: @David Siegel Yes I need homework help, and unfortunately that is what my English teach left me. That quote and the apparent presence of other works of literature have eluded me completely. I'm a senior in highschool and I'm also desperate not for the answer in which I seek but the guidance to which to take me there. I appreciate the help please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not going to rewrite the sentence, but I will give some indications of its meaning.

Conroy, in the quoted sentence, praises teachers of English for  binging the beauty of language to his knowledge. In the remainder of the paragraph he refers to various works of literature that he has enjoyed, enjoyment that he says happened because he paid attention to those teachers.

It is fine to ask for help understanding examples in school lessons or homework. It is generally not favored to simply ask people to do the homework, which is how the initial version of this question seemed to me, and apparently to others. It is better to indicate what specific problem you are having, and make it clear that this is a school assignment.